# paypal express checkout - questions marks in payment page

Tags: php, encoding, paypal

I just finished writing my php script for express checkout for my HEBREW website (database encoding is latin_swedish_ci, browser encoding windows-1255, files encoding in ANSI with notepad++).

When I pass data (written in hebrew) from the database to paypal, instead of text I see question marks. When I used utf8_encode on the text it showed gibberish.

no utf8_encode:

[image: not utf8_encode]

with utf8_encode:

[image: with utf8_encode]

Any ideas?

Comment: Holy moley. You should maybe standardize what charset you use. Preferrably unicode/utf-8.

Answer (score 3):

The key is to set UTF-8 inside your account, by the quoted steps

> 1. Login to your PayPal account
> 2. Navigate to "My Account Overview -> Profile -> My Selling Tools" section.
>      Within "More Selling Tools" click the "PayPal Button Language
>      Encoding" link.
> 3. Ensure that setting for "Your website’s language" is
>      correct.
> 4. Click the "More Options" button, select the "UTF-8" option
>      for "Encoding" and leave the "Yes" option selected for "Do you want
>      to use the same encoding for data sent from PayPal to you (e.g.,
>      IPN, downloadable logs, emails)?".
> 5. Click "Save" to save your changes.

Optionally, you may add `LocaleCode = he_IL` in your setExpressCheckout API payload, to change the checkout page language to Hebrew as well

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following:

- Set `<meta charset="utf-8">` inside your html `<head>` of your webpage.
- Set `utf-8` inside your paypal account.

Log in to your PayPal Account
click 'My selling preferences
 click on Update next to Language encoding
on the next page choose Western European Languages and click on more Options
Choose in both drop-down menues UTF-8 and click on save

Comment: But if I set the encoding to utf8 while my database uses latin would it help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set utf-8 character inside your database:

```
/* change character set to utf8 */ 
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
```

Also set file character to UTF-8 using your notepad++[image]

The idea is to set each element which contain a characters to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize paypal express checkout, specifically your locale. To change the language displayed on the PayPal pages to Hebrew, set the **`LOCALECODE`** parameter to **`he_IL`** in the SetExpressCheckout call.

Source: [Customizing Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/) (Scroll down to **Changing the Locale** section)

Keep in mind that your database encoding is UTF-8. You still need to  utf8_decode your texts before sending them to PayPal.